# Magento: How to get number of recently added products from specific category?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

**1st step:** I am using below code to get number of products from specific category:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" num_products="28" category_id="3" mode="list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But it is not limiting the products to 28 and showing all the products.

**2nd step:**
How to get recently added products first?

Comment: The class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List has no property num_products and issues no limit command when retrieving product collection for a category. It simply loads them all. The toolbar block handles pagination not the list block. I would create a custom module with a custom block which loads the collection for the given category and then adds a limit command using $collection->getSelect()->limit($this->_numProducts).

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to enable recently viewed on the product page was:

in catalog.xml inside the content block of catalog_product_view:

`<block type="reports/product_viewed" name="reports.product.viewed" as="recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml">`

`<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>`

`<action method="setItemLimit"><type>recently_viewed</type><limit>4</limit></action>`

`</block>`

in the template file: catalog/product/view.phtml:

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('recently_viewed') ?>`

OR You can call diret core as follows:

1.Place code snippet below in any template u want to add

`<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("reports/product_viewed")->setTemplate("reports/product_viewed.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>`

2.Place code snippet below in any Backend cms-> page or static block

`{{block type="reports/product_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}`

Replace template name, product_viewed.phtml with your site using.